# LG Unify External to Internal

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd, app2sd

I have a LG Unify, which has a pathetic 1.2 gigs of internal storage and I put in a 16 gig SD Card which is showing up, but all the apps pile on to the internal one and there is no Move App to SD Card option either. I have rooted it and installed numerous app2SD apps, with no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD).

- Create a new partition on your SD card, and format it to ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.
- Take your SD card and mount it in your PC.
- Repartition your SD card into two partitions, one for normal data storage(rest, fat32) and another for the linked apps (4gb, ext2). You can name the partitions whatsoever you wish.
- Now insert the SD card in your phone. Link2SD will detect it and show two partitions under storage. After this, you can refer to Link2SD's own help menu and tutorials.

You may try [GParted](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/) for partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

For obb files (for games with folders under 
/sdcard/Android/obb/,  just symlink the obb folder on the external sd card to the internal sd card,and then copy out anything there on internal storage to the symlinked folder on your external SD card. search Google for how to symlink. you need to use either the adb shell or a terminal emulator to do the symlink

Comment: this won't help you with obb files (cache) however. comment if you need help with obb files. copying them to external sd card should work. I'll add a different answer for dealing with obb files, which is probably your problem.